# How can I get localStorage to work with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, local-storage

I'm working on an MERN based web application and I'm having issues getting ReactJS to save a user token into local storage. It correctly sends data to MongoDB and gets the token back from the React UI but isn't saving the token.

This is the form: (I'm also using tailwind for styling)

```js
<form onSubmit={this.submitInfo} className="shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
                                <div className="mb-4">
                                    <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
                                        Username: 
                                        <input id="username" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.inputChange} className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"/>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div className="mb-4">
                                    <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
                                        Email: 
                                        <input id="email" className="shadow" type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.inputChange} className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"/>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div className="mb-4">
                                    <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
                                        Password: 
                                        <input id="password" type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.inputChange} className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"/>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                                    <input className="bg-primary hover:bg-highlight text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="submit" value="Signup"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

This is the function that runs when the submit button is clicked:

```js
submitInfo(event){
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/users/register`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"userName":this.state.name, "email":this.state.email, "password":this.state.password})
        })
            .then(response => localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response)))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));

        window.location.href = "/browse"
    }
```

I cant see anything inherently wrong about my implementation. I've tested the API with postman and it sends back a token perfectly fine so the issue must be on the react side. Is there something I'm overlooking?

EDIT:
I tried removing the window redirect and its still unable to save the token.

Comment: The redirect will occur before the fetch completes . You are also not preventing the default form submit process

Comment: Try `event.preventDefault();` to see if the page is redirecting before `fetch` gets a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what the comments are saying about the redirect and preventDefault, you also need to first extract the JSON object out of the response object before saving it into localStorage. You can do all of that with the following:

```js
submitInfo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch(`http://localhost:5000/users/register`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({"userName":this.state.name, "email":this.state.email, "password":this.state.password})
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(data));
      window.location.href = "/browse";
    )
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

You can read more about using the `fetch` API on the MDN docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch